# Prove that a function on $A\setminus B$ is a function on $A$ minus a function on $B$ if $f$ is injective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $f: X\rightarrow Y$ be a map and let $A,B$ be subsets of $X$. Prove that $$f(A\setminus B) =f(A)\setminus f(B) \iff f(A\setminus B)\cap(B)=\emptyset.$$

Deduce that if $f$ is injective, then $f(A\setminus B) = f(A)\setminus f(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You appear to have misstated the first result: it should be

$$f[A\setminus B]=f[A]\setminus f[B]\iff f[A\setminus B]\cap f[B]=\varnothing\;.\tag{1}$$

You have two things to prove:

1. If $f[A\setminus B]=f[A]\setminus f[B]$, then $f[A\setminus B]\cap f[B]=\varnothing$, and
2. if $f[A\setminus B]\cap f[B]=\varnothing$, then $f[A\setminus B]=f[A]\setminus f[B]$.

I’ll take you through (1) and leave the rest to you. Suppose that $f[A\setminus B]=f[A]\setminus f[B]$; you want to show that $f[A\setminus B]\cap f[B]=\varnothing$. Since by hypothesis $f[A\setminus B]=f[A]\setminus f[B]$, that’s the same as showing that $\big(f[A]\setminus f[B]\big)\cap f[B]=\varnothing$. But that’s obviously true: if $y\in f[A]\setminus f[B]$, then $y\notin f[B]$.

Now you want to assume that $f[A\setminus B]\cap f[B]=\varnothing$ and show that $f[A\setminus B]=f[A]\setminus f[B]$. I suggest that you try element chasing: show that if $y\in f[A\setminus B]$, then $y\in f[A]\setminus f[B]$, thereby showing that $f[A\setminus B]\subseteq f[A]\setminus f[B]$, and then show that if $y\in f[A]\setminus f[B]$, then $y\in f[A\setminus B]$, thereby showing that $f[A\setminus B]\supseteq f[A]\setminus f[B]$.

For the very last part of the problem, how does injectivity of $f$ relate to the righthand side of $(1)$?

Answer (score 3):

You didn't describe any context, nor had shown your own work, so the only thing I can give you, are some **hints:**

- $A \backslash B = A \cap B^c$.
- $A \cap B = \varnothing \iff A \subset B^c$.
- $A \subset B \iff A \cap B = A$.

Good luck!